# Datasource of datagridview not getting update

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I bind DataSource property of DataGridView and update it by using DataAdaptor, and its working. Now I am trying to merge DataSource from Excel file with DataSource of DataGridView and save those merge DataSource in Database, 2 datasource getting merge, but DataAdaptor unable to update this merge datasource in database, even I dont get any error while updating DataAdaptor, Here is code for merging and saving DataSource

```
        //Code for Merging DataSources
        byte[] dataTable = GetExcelFileByteArray();
        //ExcelDataTable is of type DataTable
        ExcelDataTable = GetTableDataOfByteArrayOfExcel(dataTable);
        //dgvAllGridView is DataGridVIew
        DataTable _dgvDataTable = this.dgvAllGridView.DataSource as DataTable;

        if (!ExcelDataTable.Columns.Contains("ID"))
            ExcelDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", _dgvDataTable.Columns["ID"].GetType()).SetOrdinal(0);

        _dgvDataTable.Merge(ExcelDataTable, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
        dgvAllGridView.DataSource = _dgvDataTable;

        //Code for Updatating DataAdaptor
        //DataAdaptor is a OleDBDataAdaptor
        DataAdaptor.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DataAdaptor).GetUpdateCommand();
        DataAdaptor.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DataAdaptor).GetInsertCommand();
        DataAdaptor.Update((DataTable)dgvAllGridView.DataSource);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have add `dgvAllGridView.DataSource = _dgvDataTable;` in last code ?
It will refresh your DGV datasource ..

Comment: I mean after `DataAdaptor.Update((DataTable)dgvAllGridView.DataSource);` line ? .. (on your above code ..)